# How to getfeatureinfo results in a column than a row from geoserver postgis openlayers

Tags: geoserver, javascript, wms, openlayers-2

Below is a snippet of a code I modified from openlayers. Basically, I click on a wms map and data from postgis is queried by geoserver and served on a single row table. There are 11 variables in the postgis layer called var1 through var11 if which one is dynamically chosen by the user from 20 available options. I would like to arrange the variables in a column instead of the default single row. In addition, I’d like to place the resulting table in a fix location (e.g., 900 pixels from the left edge and 1pixel from the top) within the screen instead of showing up at where one clicks or offsetted with some constant from where the click was done. Lastly, var1 to var 4 columns contain an html link to an image and I’d like to have a word or two that can be clicked to open the linked image. I suspect it got something to do with the style and popover sections of the code but have very minimal coding background so I’m stumped.

[image]

```
<style>
  html, body, #map {
    height: 100%;
  }
  #map {
    padding-top: 50px;
  }
  .legend {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
    opacity: 0.6;
  }
  .popover {
    max-width: 440px;
  }
  .popover-title {
    float: right;
    background: none;
    border: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .popover-content iframe {
    width: 400px;
    height: 120px;
    border: 0;
  }
</style>
```

and the javascript:

```
var popup = new ol.Overlay({
  element: $('#popup')
});
olMap.addOverlay(popup);

// Handle map clicks to send a GetFeatureInfo request and open the popup

olMap.on('singleclick', function(evt) {

  var view = olMap.getView();

  var url = wmsLayer.getSource().getGetFeatureInfoUrl(evt.coordinate,
      view.getResolution(), view.getProjection(), {'INFO_FORMAT': text/html'});

  popup.setPosition(evt.coordinate);

  $('#popup-content iframe').attr('src', url);

  $('#popup')

    .popover({content: function() { return $('#popup-content').html(); }})

    .popover('show');

  // Close popup when user clicks on the 'x'

  $('.popover-title').click(function() {

    $('#popup').popover('hide');

  });

});
```